# Compare two lists to find date and time overlaps in Elixir

Tags: datetime, functional-programming, list-comprehension, elixir

As part of some code that runs a booking system, we have a list of `time_slots`, which are tuples containing `{start_time, end_time}`. These are the available time slots that can be booked:

```
time_slots = [
  {~T[09:00:00], ~T[13:00:00]},
  {~T[09:00:00], ~T[17:00:00]},
  {~T[09:00:00], ~T[21:00:00]},
  {~T[13:00:00], ~T[17:00:00]},
  {~T[13:00:00], ~T[21:00:00]},
  {~T[17:00:00], ~T[21:00:00]}
]
```

Then we also have a list of bookings, which contains lists of tuples containing each `{booking_start, booking_end}`.

```
bookings = [
  [
    {~N[2019-06-13 09:00:00], ~N[2019-06-13 17:00:00]},
    {~N[2019-06-13 17:00:00], ~N[2019-06-13 21:00:00]}
  ],
  [{~N[2019-06-20 09:00:00], ~N[2019-06-20 21:00:00]}],
  [
    {~N[2019-06-22 13:00:00], ~N[2019-06-22 17:00:00]},
    {~N[2019-06-22 17:00:00], ~N[2019-06-22 21:00:00]}
  ]
]
```

In this case, we would want the results to be the two bookings with all of their `time_slots` filled up:

- `2019-06-13`
- `2019-06-20`

As they have all of their time slots filled up, and then return these results as `Date`s.

---

*To provide a bit more information:*

- For a time slot to be filled up it would require either a booking’s start or finish to overlap inside of it (regardless of how small that overlap is):

  - E.g. a booking of `0900–1000` would fill the `0900–1300`, `0900–1700` and `0900–2100` time slots
- A time slot can be filled with more than one booking:

  - E.g. we can have bookings of `0900–1000` and `1000–1200`, which would both fit inside the `0900–1300` time slot.
- If there is a booking that extends beyond the largest time slot, it counts as being filled:

  - E.g. a booking of `0800—2200` would fill the `0900–2100` time slot (along with all the others)

Comment: I think a bit more information is necessary. What does it mean for a time slot to be filled up? Is it a matching begin and end? Can a time slot be filled up with different bookings? What happens if I have a time slot from 9 to 21 but a booking from 9 to 20? Is it filled?

Comment: Thanks José, I have added some more meat to the question with examples of how the time slots would work in those situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So my understanding of the question is: for a list of bookings, do all time slots conflict with at least one booking?

A conflicting booking can be answered by checking two things:

1. If the booking starts BEFORE the time slot starts, it conflicts if the booking finishes AFTER the time slot starts.
2. If the booking starts ON OR AFTER the time slot starts, it conflicts if the BOOKING starts before the time slot finishes.

A working code therefore would look like:

```
time_slots = [
  {~T[09:00:00], ~T[13:00:00]},
  {~T[09:00:00], ~T[17:00:00]},
  {~T[09:00:00], ~T[21:00:00]},
  {~T[13:00:00], ~T[17:00:00]},
  {~T[13:00:00], ~T[21:00:00]},
  {~T[17:00:00], ~T[21:00:00]}
]

bookings = [
  [
    {~N[2019-06-13 09:00:00], ~N[2019-06-13 17:00:00]},
    {~N[2019-06-13 17:00:00], ~N[2019-06-13 21:00:00]}
  ],
  [{~N[2019-06-20 09:00:00], ~N[2019-06-13 21:00:00]}],
  [
    {~N[2019-06-22 13:00:00], ~N[2019-06-22 17:00:00]},
    {~N[2019-06-22 17:00:00], ~N[2019-06-22 21:00:00]}
  ]
]

bookings
|> Enum.filter(fn booking ->
  Enum.all?(time_slots, fn {time_start, time_end} ->
    Enum.any?(booking, fn {booking_start, booking_end} ->
      if Time.compare(booking_start, time_start) == :lt do
        Time.compare(booking_end, time_start) == :gt
      else
        Time.compare(booking_start, time_end) == :lt
      end
    end)
  end)
end) 
|> Enum.map(fn [{booking_start, _} | _] -> NaiveDateTime.to_date(booking_start) end)
```

PS: note you should not compare time/date/datetime with `>`, `<` and friends. Always use the relevant compare functions.

Comment: This is working perfectly, thank you. I did not know that about time comparison (so good to know that too)!

Answer (score 1):

Although this might not cover all cases, given the sample data you provided this would work

```
defmodule BookingsTest do
  @slots [
    {~T[09:00:00], ~T[13:00:00]},
    {~T[09:00:00], ~T[17:00:00]},
    {~T[09:00:00], ~T[21:00:00]},
    {~T[13:00:00], ~T[17:00:00]},
    {~T[13:00:00], ~T[21:00:00]},
    {~T[17:00:00], ~T[21:00:00]}
  ]

  def booked_days(bookings, time_slots \\ @slots) do
    Enum.reduce(bookings, [], fn(day_bookings, acc) ->
      Enum.reduce(day_bookings, time_slots, fn({%{hour: s_time}, %{hour: e_time}}, ts) ->

          Enum.reduce(ts, [], fn
            ({%{hour: slot_s}, %{hour: slot_e}} = slot, inner_acc) ->

              case is_in_slot(s_time, e_time, slot_s, slot_e) do
                true -> inner_acc
                _ -> [slot | inner_acc]
              end

          end)
      end)
      |> case do
           [] -> [day_bookings | acc]
           _ -> acc
         end
    end)
    |> Enum.reduce([], fn([{arb, _} | _], acc) -> [NaiveDateTime.to_date(arb) | acc] end)
  end

  def is_in_slot(same_start, _, same_start, _), do: true
  def is_in_slot(s_time, e_time, slot_s, slot_e) when s_time < slot_s and e_time > slot_s, do: true
  def is_in_slot(s_time, e_time, slot_s, slot_e) when s_time > slot_s and s_time < slot_e, do: true
  def is_in_slot(_, _, _, _), do: false
end



> bookings = [
  [
    {~N[2019-06-13 10:00:00], ~N[2019-06-13 17:00:00]},
    {~N[2019-06-13 17:00:00], ~N[2019-06-13 21:00:00]}
  ],
  [{~N[2019-06-20 09:00:00], ~N[2019-06-20 21:00:00]}],
  [
    {~N[2019-06-22 13:00:00], ~N[2019-06-22 17:00:00]},
    {~N[2019-06-22 17:00:00], ~N[2019-06-22 21:00:00]}
  ]
]

> BookingsTest.booked_days(bookings)
[~D[2019-06-13], ~D[2019-06-20]]
```

The idea is, reduce through the `bookings` list accumulating into an empty list, each enumeration will be the list of occupied slots for the day.

Reduce through this list, accumulating with the list of all time slots available.

Inside this reduce through the timeslots accumulator into an empty list.

For each slot check if the start and end time of the current day booking slot overlaps into the slot. If it does just return the inner accumulator as is. If it doesn't, add the slot into this accumulator.

In the end of the `day_bookings` reduction, if you have an empty list it means no slot remains available for the day. So you add it to the outer accumulator, this will be the list of fully booked days.

In the end you reduce again the results so to invert them and in the process set each element to be the Date, instead of the list of bookings for the day.

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive solution and the excellent explanation. It is working perfectly.

Comment: You welcome @gosseti, I think José's solution is more readable though

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a typo in the second booking and it does not start almost a week *after* it’s own end, the solution might be much simpler than careful reducing.

The slots are filled when the booking starts and ends exactly at:

```rb
{start, end} =
  time_slots
  |> Enum.flat_map(&Tuple.to_list/1)
  |> Enum.min_max()          
#⇒ {~T[09:00:00], ~T[21:00:00]}
```

Which make the check almost trivial:

```rb
Enum.filter(bookings, fn booking ->
  {s, e} = {Enum.map(booking, &elem(&1, 0)), Enum.map(booking, &elem(&1, 1))}
  with {[s], [e]} <- {s -- e, e -- s} do
    same_date =
      [s, e]
      |> Enum.map(&NaiveDateTime.to_date/1)
      |> Enum.reduce(&==/2)
    full = Enum.map([s, e], &NaiveDateTime.to_time/1)

    same_date and full == [start, end]
  end
end)
```

`Kernel.SpecialForms.with/1` guarantees that whatever not expected will be filtered out.

Comment: I am getting a `undefined function b/0` from L2 where you have `Enum.map(b, &elem(&1, 1))`

Comment: Fixed, sorry. Leftover.